# SSIS Import .csv

Tags: sql-server, ssis, csv

I’m new to SSIS and I’ve got an existing SSIS task which is importing a CSV file that has some unusual formatting.

The CSV has formatting like this:

```
TaskID, TaskName
ABC,Test Entry ABCD,Test’s Complete
```

The format of the file needs to change to:

```
TaskID, TaskName
ABC,Test Entry ABCD,”Test’s Complete”
```

Looking for some general advice as to how that change can be made, I don’t see anything obvious in the connection Manager to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the "Text qualifier" option of the Flat File Connection Manager.
As you can see in the image below, the default value is `<none>`, but you will change it to `"` to have your expected output.

[image]

By doing that, SSIS will add the character defined as a Text qualifier at the beginning and end of your string columns.

If you need to have a column without the Text qualifier (""), then you can change the option Text Qualified to `False` on the Advanced menu of the column. By default, this option is set to `True`.
[image]

More details can be found on [Flat File Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hmm, the settings on the package already match this.

Comment: Have you changed the Text Qualifier from <none> to " ? (As described, not like the picture)